# Echo image - PHP & JSON - Twitter API

Tags: php, javascript, variables, twitter, youtube

New to PHP, and found a solid code that's able to retrieve JSON data from Twitter API and echo it out. Here's the PHP code that retrieves the user-pic of @Guardian (newspaper)

```
 <?php
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=guardian'), true);
   echo $data[0]['profile_image_url'];
 ?>
```

The JSON data for the image is:

> profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1857791844/G_twittermain_normal.jpg"

So obviously it echoes the url (text), i'd like to **output the actual image** and possibly have control over the sizing of it too if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to display image on html ? or want to save on your server fore resizing

Answer (score 1):

```
    <img src=" <?php echo $data[0]['profile_image_url'];?>" />
</body>
```

Comment: Accept answer to get more help from stackoverflow people :)

Comment: If you output a URL into HTML context, you have to escape it. `<img src=" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data[0]['profile_image_url'], ENT_QUOTES);?>" />` - wont change a bit in this case, but what if evil characters in the URL mess with your HTML?